# solspace favorite 4.0 if variable

Tags: solspace

Just upgraded my solspace favorite to version 4.0.

In favorite version 3 I could use

```
  {if saved}{/if} and {if not_saved}{/if}
```

My question:
I want to use a variable to set my css to "active"
So if I already added that member to my favorites the link will be red.
If not than the link will be blue.

What I tried so far and does not work:

```
  {exp:favorites:info username="{visitor:email}" disable_pagination="yes"}
  {if favorites:favorite_id == "{favorites:favorite_id}"}
```

or

```
  {exp:favorites:members favorites_username="{visitor:email}" disable_pagination="yes"}
  {if favorites_username == "{visitor:email}"}
  <li class="item-1 active"><a href="#">fav</a></li>
  {if:else}
  <li class="item-1"><a href="#">fav</a></li>
  {/if} 
  {/exp:favorites:members}
```

Hope someone could point me in the right direction...

Solspace Favorite 4.0.2
Expressionengine 2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a member has been favorited, you would use `{exp:favorites:info}` and check if there are any results (which means the member has been favorited) or not (which means the member has not been favorited). Eg:

```
{exp:favorites:info member_id="3"}
    RED (favorited)
    {if favorites:no_results}
        BLUE (not favorited)
    {/if}
{/exp:favorites:info}
```

As with any "if no_results"-type conditionals, when that conditional is true, everything outside of the conditional will not parse nor be displayed (which is why "RED" isn't wrapped with anything above).